# Prolog, number of sections between points

Tags: prolog

I have a task to do in Prolog. It seems to be easy, but I am really novice in this kind of language and I can't get use to it.

I have to write a function `path_L(a,z,N)` , where `a,z` - edges o a "road", N is the variable that I am looking for. So, there are many edges defining one-way direction: `edge(a,b)`, `edge(b,c)`, `edge(b,d)`, `edge(e,f)`, etc. The goal of the `path_L` function is to give a result that is the number of sections between `(a,z)` in the form of `N=result`. So if for example:

```
path_L(a,b,N). -> N=1
path_L(a,c,N). -> N=2
```

I have already defined another function defining if a path between (X,Y) exists:

```
path(X,Y):-edge(X,Y).
path(X,Y):-edge(X,Z),path(Z,Y).
```

Comment: Have you been through a basic Prolog tutorial or have a Prolog text book you're using? Your attempt has basic syntax errors.

Comment: Actually, I only had one lecture:) What errors do You mean?

Comment: `=` is for unification. To define a *predicate* (prolog doesn't have functions), you use `:-`.

Comment: thanks, I've corrected it:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, like @lurker said, that you meant your predicates for finding a path are:

```
path(X,Y):- edge(X,Y).
path(X,Y):- edge(X,Z), path(Z,Y).
```

And given a few clauses stating the existance of edges as:

```
edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).
edge(c,d).
```

You got the right idea that `path_L` should have an additional argument for the 'count' of edges between nodes. A simple version of what you want (with some caveats) is below:

```
path_L(X,Y,1):- edge(X,Y).
path_L(X,Y,R):- edge(X,Z), path_L(Z,Y,N), R is N+1.
```

Notice how that the first case simply unifies the third argument with '1', so an objective clause like `path_L(a,b,2)` ("Distance between a and b is 2") correctly fails, while `path_L(a,b,R)` (notice R is a variable) succeeds with R unifying with 1. It's a neat feature of the paradigm that the same definition is good for 'both ways'.

Another example is the objective `path_L(a,B,2)` (notice B is a variable), which succeeds with B unifying with `c` - because `c` is the node with a distance of 2 from `a`.

Finally, assume instead a graph given by:

```
edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).
edge(c,d).
edge(d,x).
edge(a,x).
```

An objective clause like `path_L(a,x,R)` should *first* succeed with R = 1, and then, if requested (pressing `;` on your terminal) with R = 4. This is because there are *two* valid paths (with lenghts 1 and 4) from `a` to `x`. The *order of the predicates* matters - if you defined `path_L` as such:

```
path_L(X,Y,R):- edge(X,A), path_L(A,Y,N), R is N+1. 
path_L(X,Y,1):- edge(X,Y).
```

That same query would result *first* in R=4, and then in R=1. This is because the **order in which predicates are defined matter**. In fact, the mechanisms through which Prolog choose which predicates to test and how clauses are chosen for 'solving the problem' are well defined; and you should definitely [look it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution) if you get into logic programming.

Hope this helps.

P.S.: about those caveats - e.g., none of the above allow a path of zero-length from a node to itself. Depending on what you want, that could be the case or a mistake.

Comment: Thank You very much, it's awesome answer, I get it now:)

Comment: Btw, is there anything quite easy I could do to get the N=0 if the situation mentioned by You occurs?

Comment: @PawełPoręba, `path_L(X, X, 0).`

Comment: Hi, I've just noticed, that when I add `path_L(X,X,0)`, it doubles the amount of the scores. I mean, for instance path_L(a,c) results in:
N=2, N=2.